# How to stop thinking on reasoning?

Tags: logic

I think  I always think on the base of reasons and logically, but relations have problems with Reasons and Logic. Like if we Trust some one, we should do without demanding the explanations.

is it a good way to think logically ?

if no then what is the good way ?

and how to achieve it ?

Comment: The "right way of thinking" will depend on what you are trying to achieve. E.g. if you want to pass a math-test, logical thinking is better than trying to feel the right answer. If you are in a car-race you might want to rely on your intuition rather than calculating centrifugal forces and friction. If you are dancing, thinking "yeah!" works fine (for me). So the choice depends on the purpose. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in some situations it is a fallacy to think too logically, particularly when human relations are involved.
I would give the following reasons for not thinking too logically:

- you might fail to see that the situation is too complex for you to grasp. Logic applies well with certainty, i.e. when working on certain premisses to derive a certain conclusion. In real life, bayesian reasonning would be more appropriate to deal with uncertainty but sometimes you can't even evaluate degrees of certainty, let alone take into account some crucial parameters whose existence you don't even imagine. Using logic could be profundly misguided. Trusting others could be the most rational move.
- logic does not tell you what you ought to do. At best it tells you how to achieve something you ought to do. You might sometimes pursue a wrong goal just for the sake of logic, because this goal is amenable to quantification and logical reasonning- here is a somehow stereotyped example: you might decide to earn money at the expanse of a happier life because money is amenable to utility decision while happiness is difficult to evaluate, if possible at all. In other words: when you have a hammer in hand, everything looks like a nail. It can be rational, sometimes, to try different tools...

For these reasons, it might be rational in some situations to rely not on pure reasoning, but also on the built-in adaptative system on which your higher-level abilities rest, i.e. your intuitions and emotions.
It seems to me that this is particularly true in social situations, because the situations are usually complex, and because "what you ought to do" in life might be an irreducibly social matter in the end.